# How does Snowflake handle case sensitivity in object identifiers?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake, if I run commands like the following:

```
create temporary table "Tab" (i int);
select * from "Tab"; -- this works
select * from Tab; -- error
```

I get the following error:

> SQL compilation error: Object 'TAB' does not exist or not authorized.

Snowflake's [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html#controlling-case-using-the-quoted-identifiers-ignore-case-parameter) claim that Unquoted object identifiers are case-insensitive. If that's true, why is it looking for `TAB`? And why doesn't it recognize that `Tab` (or `TAB`) refers to the same thing as `"Tab"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Snowflake's documentation on this point was technically inaccurate and misleading. It has now been updated to read:

> Unquoted object identifiers ... Are stored and resolved as uppercase characters (e.g. `id` is stored and resolved as `ID`).

Unquoted identifiers in Snowflake always resolve as if they were in all-capitals.

If the `QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS_IGNORE_CASE` parameter is changed from its default (`FALSE`) to `TRUE`, then quoted identifiers are given the same behavior. Despite the parameter's name, this doesn't mean the identifiers are case-insensitive: they just resolve to all-capitals, which matches the behavior of unquoted identifiers.

**Important**: That means that if you ever create any table, field, etc., with double-quotes around its name, using the default settings (`QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS_IGNORE_CASE` = `FALSE`), and the quoted name is not in all-capitals:

- You will never be able to refer to that object without using quoted identifiers.
- You will never be able to refer to that object with `QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS_IGNORE_CASE` set to `TRUE`, even with quoted identifiers. Or, as [the docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html#impact-of-changing-the-parameter) say:

  > If the parameter is then changed to TRUE, the identifier for the newly-created object is ***not*** retrievable/resolvable.

Knowing this, it seems the safest approach would be to set `QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS_IGNORE_CASE` to `TRUE` at the Account level when you're first getting started with Snowflake, so it becomes the default policy. As long as you keep that setting consistently, then the statement that "Unquoted object identifiers are case-insensitive" will become *effectively* true for you.

[The docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html#impact-of-changing-the-parameter) provide the following Tip:

> Due to the impact that changing the parameter can have on resolving identifiers, we ***highly*** recommend choosing an identifier resolution method early in your implementation of Snowflake and then dictating the default behavior by setting the parameter at the account level accordingly, which can be done by any account administrator for your account. The parameter can always be overridden at the session level, but we don’t encourage changing the parameter from the default, unless you have an explicit need to do so.

If there's ever a corner case where you need to be able to refer to something case-sensitively, you can change the `QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS_IGNORE_CASE` setting for that particular session. These situations should be rare, because when consuming "SHOW" results (which is the commonly-cited case for using quoted identifiers) setting `QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS_IGNORE_CASE` to `TRUE` obviates the need for quoted identifiers through some magic beyond my understanding.

```
alter session set quoted_identifiers_ignore_case = false;
show tables;

-- This fails because `name` resolves to `NAME` rather than `"name"`
select name
from table(result_scan(last_query_id()));

alter session set quoted_identifiers_ignore_case = true;
show tables;

-- This succeeds, for some reason, even though `name` still resolves to `NAME`.
select name
from table(result_scan(last_query_id()));
```

Note: Database Collation settings appear to have no impact on the behaviors of identifiers in Snowflake.

Comment: Thanks Stripling! I'm taking this feedback to the docs team

Comment: FYI, the docs have been updated. Let me know what you think - and thanks for the feedback! https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html

Comment: @FelipeHoffa: Thank you. That's much clearer now!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above. Snowflake actually converts everything to uppercase when resolving identifiers.

This is normally not an issue if you build queries or objects within Snowflake, but when you build them from an external source (For example, a Python script or an Alteryx workflow), you need to be sure to use the exact casing you used in the external resource, because Snowflake will not convert those object names to uppercase. So if you use Alteryx to create a column named `Record_id`, the only way to reference it within snowflake would be to actually respect the casing: `Record_id`. Things like `RECORD_ID` or `record_id` will throw an invalid identifier error.

Comment: Good call-out. More specifically, the only way to reference the column within snowflake would be to change `QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS_IGNORE_CASE` to `FALSE` _and_ use double-quotes around the name: `"Record_id"`.